# How can I get d value from process.stdout.write(d)

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I have that 'd' where is stored the access token, how can I get this value from him, if I'm using **console.log(d)** I'm getting this:

```
 <Buffer 7b 22 61 63 63 65 73 73 5f 74 6f 6b 65 6e 22 3a 22 65 61 38 30 66 32 30 35 38 38 32 37 34 64 37 32 62 61 64 66 30 36 31 37 64 36 37 62 36 65 34 38 22 ... 362 more bytes>
```

I tried with `toString(),str='',str+=d` but I can't get it

```
const auth=()=>{
    const data=querystring.stringify({
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        client_id: 'x',
        client_secret: 'x',
    })
    var options = {
      port:443,
      host: 'rest.sandbox.eu.zuora.com',
      path:'/oauth/token',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': data.length
       },
       method: 'POST',
    };
    const req=https.request(options,(res)=>{
    
        res.on('data', (d) => {
         process.stdout.write(d)
         }).on('end',()=>{
             console.log("Yay");
         });
    })
    req.write(data)
    req.end()
    }
    auth()
```

Comment: What output to you get with toString()?

Comment: I m stupid..yes that's the response I need to use JSON.parse(d.toString()) now i get the object with the access token! You opened my mind:)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (not tested)

```
const auth=()=>{
    const data=querystring.stringify({
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        client_id: 'x',
        client_secret: 'x',
    })
    var options = {
      port:443,
      host: 'rest.sandbox.eu.zuora.com',
      path:'/oauth/token',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': data.length
       },
       method: 'POST',
    };
    const req=https.request(options,(res)=>{
    
        let body = []
        res.on('data', (d) => {
            body.push(d)
        }).on('end',()=>{
            try {
                console.log(JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString()));
            } catch(e) {
                console.log('some error')
            }
         });
    })
    req.write(data)
    req.end()
    }
    auth()
```

Comment: It works,thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are using `toString`, but if I invoke `toString()`, as

```
theString = d.toString()
```

it works for me.